# R-create a data frame inside this loop

Tags: r

How can I create a data frame inside this loop based on the calculated variables?

Script:

```
for (i in  1:nrow(newData)){
  X<-newData[i,1]
  Y<-newData[i,2]
  dRatio <- ((X-Xmean)/(Y-Ymean)) 
  dataList <- data.frame(X,Y,dRatio)
}
```

Comment: `dataList = cbind(newData[,1], newData[,2], (newData[,1]-Xmean)/(newData[,2]-Xmean))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this vectorized:

```
dataList <- newData[,1:2]
dataList$dRatio <- ((newData[,1]-Xmean)/(newData[,2]-Ymean))
```

Or if you persist to use your own code:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow(newData), 3)
for (i in  1:nrow(newData)){
  X<-newData[i,1]
  Y<-newData[i,2]
  dRatio <- ((X-Xmean)/(Y-Ymean)) 
  m[i,] <- c(X,Y,dRatio)
}
dataList <- as.data.frame(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list to hold dataframes  outside of your loop

```
dataList<-list()
for (i in  1:nrow(newData)){
  X<-newData[i,1]
  Y<-newData[i,2]
  dRatio <- ((X-Xmean)/(Y-Ymean)) 
  dataList[[i]] <- data.frame(X,Y,dRatio)
}
```

Comment: this create a list, any way to create a data frame?

Comment: This will create a list of dataframes.